# Smallest Icons in the corners of my watch missing in spite of filled all placeholders

Tags: swiftui, icons, assets, watchkit, apple-watch-complication

My app runs flawlessly on both the iPhone and the watch.  The transfer of the icons with the Prepo app works fine.  Only the small corners on the watch are filled with a square instead of the round logo.
Where and how do I have to save the smallest icons in the asset.xcassets?

I am using swiftUI and Xcode 12.4 for coding and found some hints here, which didn't help for me :
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/overview/complications/

The suggested sizes 40x40 and 44x44 pt are filled and 2 new ones appear without specifications. I tried 20x20 and 22x22 which didn't work.

The code in my ComplicationController:

import ClockKit

class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {

```
// MARK: - Complication Configuration

func getComplicationDescriptors(handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> Void) {
    let descriptors = [
        CLKComplicationDescriptor(identifier: "complication", displayName: "BouleR", supportedFamilies: CLKComplicationFamily.allCases)
        // Multiple complication support can be added here with more descriptors
    ]
    
    // Call the handler with the currently supported complication descriptors
    handler(descriptors)
}

func handleSharedComplicationDescriptors(_ complicationDescriptors: [CLKComplicationDescriptor]) {
    // Do any necessary work to support these newly shared complication descriptors
}

// MARK: - Timeline Configuration

func getTimelineEndDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the last entry date you can currently provide or nil if you can't support future timelines
    handler(nil)
}

func getPrivacyBehavior(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationPrivacyBehavior) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with your desired behavior when the device is locked
    handler(.showOnLockScreen)
}

// MARK: - Timeline Population

func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the current timeline entry
    handler(nil)
}

func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, after date: Date, limit: Int, withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the timeline entries after the given date
    handler(nil)
}

// MARK: - Sample Templates

func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
    // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
    handler(nil)
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code in your ComplicationController where you define what complications you support? It sounds like you have all the assets but if you're not defining all desired complication templates they won't show up.

Comment: Thx,good luck with the posted infos. Sorry, I just read your comment. Franz